# BusinessHours.diff fetches dofferent values for the different business hours setting why?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have the two business hours configured 1 of SLA and other for OLA calculations.

**SLA Hours**
[image]

**OLA Hours**
[image]

Although both the business hours are configured for 9 hours, but still code is not calculating the values correctly. For the 1st business hour it calculates 106 hours and for other it calculates 108 hours, why ? I have shared the code below for reference

```
Date startDate = Date.today();  // 9/18/2017
Date endDate = Date.today().addDays(16); // 10/4/2017

BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id,Name,IsActive,IsDefault,MondayEndTime,MondayStartTime 
                                      FROM BusinessHours 
                                      WHERE Name = 'SLA Hours'];

Datetime startTime = Datetime.newInstance(startDate.year(), startDate.month(), startDate.day());
Datetime endTime = Datetime.newInstance(endDate.year(), endDate.month(), endDate.day());
System.debug('START_TIME :: '+startTime);
System.debug('END_TIME :: '+endTime);

// API to calculate the business hours difference        
Long difference = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, startDate, endDate);

// calculate the minutes from Milisecond value
Integer diffInminutes = Integer.valueOf(difference / (1000*60));
System.debug('DIFF IN HOURS :: '+diffInminutes/60);
```

[image]

Here is the another output

[image]

Again If my business hours like below then
[image]

and then

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the timezones in your Business Hours screen shots are different.
Second, you are constructing your DateTimes in your local timezone as set on your user record, not sure what that is.

Take a look at the [Support Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_support.htm) page in the Apex Dev guide, it has examples on how to work with Business Hours.

Comment: Thanks ! What is the recommended approach for this. Which timezone do I need to construct the timezone ? How can I get the exact 108 hours difference? Could you please guide?